# How to get the position of overlay geometry on hover?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In my forge viewer project I am trying to add point-cloud markup to mark selected items in some saved viewpoint. I can create the markers using below code-

```js
 createPointCloud(points, overlayName) { 

    if (points.length > 0) {
        try {
            const vertexShader = `
            attribute vec4 color;
            varying vec4 vColor;
            void main() {
                vec4 vPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vPosition;
                gl_PointSize = 20.0;
                vColor = color;
            }
            `;

            // Fragment Shader code
            const fragmentShader = `
            #ifdef GL_ES
            precision highp float;
            #endif
            varying vec4 vColor;
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vColor;
            }
            `

            // Shader material parameters
            this.shader = {
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                depthWrite: this.occlusion,
                depthTest: this.occlusion,
                fragmentShader,
                vertexShader,
                attributes: {
                    color: {
                        type: 'v4',
                        value: []
                    }
                }
            }

            // Initialize geometry vertices
            // and shader attribute colors
            this.geometry = new THREE.Geometry()

            for (const point of points) {

                this.geometry.vertices.push(
                    new THREE.Vector3(point.position.x, point.position.y, point.position.z))

                this.shader.attributes.color.value.push(
                    new THREE.Vector4(
                        point.color.r/255.00,
                        point.color.g / 255.00,
                        point.color.b / 255.00,
                        1.0)
                )
            }

            // creates shader material
            let shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(this.shader);

            // creates THREE.PointCloud
            let pointCloud = new THREE.PointCloud(
                this.geometry, shaderMaterial)

            this.overlayPointCloudMap[overlayName] = pointCloud; 

            this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(overlayName);
            this.viewer.impl.addOverlay(overlayName, pointCloud); 

        } catch (ex) {

            alert('Can\'t show points, please try again!');
        }

    }

}
```

Also want to show some modal on hover over the markup. To do that I need to know the position of the markup that is currently hovered. I've tried a solution based on [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card). But not able to get the correct item. Sometimes it returns empty list. The hit-test code is like below-

```js
updateHitTest(event) {
      
    const pointer = event.pointers ? event.pointers[0] : event;

    const pointerVector = new THREE.Vector3();
    const pointerDir = new THREE.Vector3();
    const ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
    ray.params.PointCloud.threshold = 20; // hit-test markup size = 20
    const camera = this.viewer.impl.camera;
    const rect = this.viewer.impl.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = ((pointer.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width) * 2 - 1;
    const y = - ((pointer.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * 2 + 1;
    if (camera.isPerspective) {
        pointerVector.set(x, y, 0.5);
        pointerVector.unproject(camera);
        ray.set(camera.position, pointerVector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    } else {
        pointerVector.set(x, y, -1);
        pointerVector.unproject(camera);
        pointerDir.set(0, 0, -1);
        ray.set(pointerVector, pointerDir.transformDirection(camera.matrixWorld));
    } 
     

    let nodes = [];

    // loop through all the overlays and intersect with the respected point-cloud
    for (const overlay of this.overlayNames) {
        nodes = nodes.concat( ray.intersectObject(this.overlayPointCloudMap[overlay]));
         
    } 

    if (nodes.length > 0) {
        if (this.lastClickedIndex != nodes[0].index) {
            this.lastClickedIndex = nodes[0].index;
            console.log(this.lastClickedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to figure out where to change or how can I get the job done? TIA

Answer (score 0):

The code seems alright. But you may need to adjust the `ray.params.PointCloud.threshold` value. Also, try debugging the three.js code by adding a single point to the point cloud, and stepping into the `ray.intersectObject` method to see it can't find it.

Alternatively, if the number of points/markers you expect to have on screen is "reasonable", consider the approach of adding them as HTML elements overlaying the 3D view es explained in https://github.com/autodesk-forge/forge-extensions/tree/master/public/extensions/IconMarkupExtension.