# How to create points in forge viewer using SceneBuilder and BufferGeometry?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In the developer guide [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/scene-builder/), forge has mentioned that we can create points using SceneBuilder extension and BufferGeometry. We need to set **isPoint** of BufferGeometry to **true** to do this. My approach to create just one point in the scene was like below

```js
async function addASinglePoint() {

await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
const ext = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');



modelBuilder = await ext.addNewModel({
    conserveMemory: false,
    modelNameOverride: 'A Single Marker'
  });

  const red = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0)
  }); 

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute([0, 0, 0], 3));
  geometry.isPoints = true; 

  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, red);

  mesh.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
  );

  mesh.dbId = 234543;
  modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);

}
```

But I can't see any points in viewer. In the **Model** browser I can see the item is added and If I click the item it seems viewer navigate to the item. But I can't see anything other than the pivot point. It's maybe I haven't set the point size. I couldn't find any way to set the size of the point. How can I set the size of the point and show it in viewer? And If I need to add more points (100-200), what will be the proper way to do that? TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in adding point clouds to the viewer, there's a couple of options:

- using the standard `THREE.PointCloud` class as shown here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-point-clouds-forge-viewer (your approach is similar to it so it might work as well, but you'll probably need to use the `THREE.PointCloudMaterial` as well)
- using [Potree](https://github.com/potree/potree) as shown in this code sample: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo

Comment: I tried using PointCloud and succeeded. But failed to interact with the points. Now I am trying using SceneBuilder. I need to show some interactive markers. Problem is SceneBuilder supports only some material types (MeshPhong, MeshBasic, LineBasic and Prism), not PointCloudMaterial.

Comment: Ah I see... If you need your points to be interactive, consider something like this: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card.

Comment: Yes, that's the initial blog I followed. But got wrong intersected objects. Sometimes empty array. I posted a question for that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890954/how-to-get-the-position-of-overlay-geometry-on-hover/67088434#67088434

Comment: Have you tried the recommendations mentioned in the other SO question?

Comment: Yes I tried different approaches with PointCloud like changing the threshold and intersecting a single point. But didn't worked for me. As I said, it sometime gives me empty array. But didn't tried the html markup.  Because html markup has some overhead like changing the markup positions etc. We wanted point cloud to work.